# I'm confused about this statement, Object.entries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, logic, use-effect

```
useEffect(() => {
  cat &&
    setFilteredProducts(
      products.filter((item) =>
        Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) =>
          item[key].includes(value)
        )
      )
    );
}, [products, cat, filters]);
```

I've been watching the video, over and over again but I can't seem to understand it properly, can somebody help me explain this line by line? I've get the point about *"cat &&"* but the rest confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the above code line by line:

I am assuming you have a state variable with a setter function `setFilteredProducts` and two arrays `products` and `filters`, each having objects as values.

We are setting values in the state variable from the filtered values stored in the `products` variable.

`Object.entries` simply returns an array, where each item is an array with its first value as keys and the second value as the corresponding value, `every` is another function that applies  on the array returned by the `Object.entries` function

The `every` function takes in a callback function as an argument, which tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the callback.

In this case, the test implemented is `item[key].includes(value)`, which tests whether each iterated element(an object) in the products array has an array corresponding to `key` with `value` in it.

You can refer to
`Object.entries` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

`Array.prototype.every`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

`Array.prototype.filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

`Array.prototype.includes`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0):

you most your productlist.js check .i think there is a problem .when you have handleFilters check your value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).